# Kernel crashes when plotting $z=\sqrt{(x^2 + y^2)}^0$

Tags: plotting, bugs, kernel, crash

**Bug introduced in 7.0.1 or earlier and fixed in 10.0.1**

---

I'm plotting a 3D function, which makes Mathematica V9 (running on Windows 7) crash all the time. Does this only happen for me or for somebody else as well?

```
Plot3D[(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

(I know that this function alone is not useful, but I found it in a much more complex function, and tracked down the actual source). If I use a power of something other than 0, it works.

The error-message is:

> **Mathematica Kernel for Windows has stopped working**
>
> Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.

Can somebody confirm the problem?

Comment: This still crashes (without an error message) in Mathematica V10.0. If I had a dollar for every time the Mathematica Kernel reset itself silently (after losing all my work), I would have a couple of WholeFoods shopping trips. **PS** This is on Windows 8.1.

Comment: confirmed, but so what? The workaround is "don't do that"..  (Wrapping the expression in `Evaluate` fixes it.. )

Comment: Confirmed with V10 running on OS X.

Comment: @george2079 I know that one can workaround by not doing it. but the problem arose in a serios calculation where some terms cancled such that the problematic part appeared. For this question, I have tracked the problem down to reduce "noise" in the question.

Comment: crashing of the kernel happens regularily for you? it has never occured in such a deterministic way as in this function.

Comment: "Regularly" is putting it strongly, but "not infrequently".

Comment: @george2079 I'd argue that the kernel should *never* crash, and instances in which it does so in a reproducible way should be considered bugs. If this is really a "don't do that" situation, it should print an error message rather than taking down the entire kernel.

Comment: @Guillochon precisely!

Comment: @NicoDean  There was one day last week when neither the kernel nor the front end crashed on me.

Comment: completely agreed with previous commenters that "don't do that" is the wrong response. The kernel should NEVER crash, and for that it doesn't matter how the crash was produced. The crash itself is the problem. The existence of a work-around is *never* sufficient to accept a kernel crash. It's like saying "if a certain plane type repeatedly crashes, don't use the plane, drive by car". We can't acquit the faulty system just because we can adapt our behavior (how we cope with the problem). It's still a problem.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I hope you made the necessary sacrifices to the gods.

Comment: In Linux the kernel crashes silently without error message.

Comment: Interestingly, `Plot3D[Limit[(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^t, t -> 0], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]` plots OK.

Comment: @halirutan back in the old days we had to WORK to make sure the bugs ported over to other OSes... :)

Comment: It does not crash at Mathematica6, Windows XP :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Glad to note this is fixed in 10.0.1.

Comment: Can anybody confirm this? (this comment is done by a newly unregistered user, who made his first comment. just to be sure.)

Comment: @NicoDean Yes, I can confirm this.

Comment: Someone flagged this as not an answer.  In some way I think it is the *best* answer, when true, other than perhaps a robust patch.  I think Accepting this answer may be appropriate, therefore I do not wish to convert it to a comment.  If anyone disagrees with this please consider making your argument on http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/ so that the community can decide how this should be handled.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I flagged it as such but did not downvote. Both "answers" seem to be simple comments to me but I can't say that I feel strongly enough to make a meta post.

Comment: @Mark I think a good case can be made for the first one being a comment as it can't possibly resolve the issue like a patch or a "this is fixed in ..." however as you can see this answer has been Accepted.  I think that is a reasonable result.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yeah, I'm fine with that.

Comment: I can confirm that it is also fixed on a Mac by version 10.0.1